# How to Write a sub query inside serverside datatables [ignited datatable]

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables, serverside-javascript

How to Write a sub query inside serverside datatables ,does anyone have any idea ?

now we are following a method of ignited-datatables by ahmed-samy

Here's reference link [link](http://www.ahmed-samy.com/php-codeigniter-full-featrued-jquery-datatables-part-2)!

```
$this->datatables->select('C.cls_id,S.std_name,B.bat_name,SE.name,C.standard,C.batch,C.status');
 $this->datatables->join('standards AS S','S.std_id = C.standard','LEFT');
 $this->datatables->join('batches AS B','B.bat_id = C.batch','LEFT');
 $this->datatables->join('sections AS SE','SE.id = C.section','LEFT');
 echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

I would like to know how we can write a sub-query inside these statements 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys finally Figured it out !!
thanks to ellislab forms

we could use sub-quires inside the server side datatable as follows :

```
    $this->datatables->select('S.stf_id, S.stf_firstname, S.stf_lastname, t1.cnt_mon');

    //Here Our Subquery Goes -- Inside datatables->from
    $this->datatables->from('staffs as S 
                    LEFT JOIN 
                    ( 
                       SELECT teacher, COUNT(teacher) as cnt_mon 
                       FROM timetable as T
                       WHERE day = 1 AND ac_year = '.$this->session->userdata("cur_ac_year").'
                       GROUP BY teacher     
                    ) t1 ON t1.teacher = S.stf_id');
    echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

Here It shows How to write -> https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/160896/P180/#912045

Comment: i have a similar issue like this. ..can u help?

Comment: can you help me to solve this,please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646188/i-want-to-convert-this-query-in-codeigniter-to-ignited-datatable-query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646188/i-want-to-convert-this-query-in-codeigniter-to-ignited-datatable-query this is my question